# window.open doesn't open in same session

Tags: javascript, session

I'm using the below anchor tag on a JSP page to open another page from the same application, but the new window is not opened in the same session and instead it redirects to the login page of my application. Any clues why?

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('/path_to_same_page', '_blank',
        'toolbar=0,status=0,resizable=1'); return false;">Click here...</a>
```

Comment: Probably some browser setting.. you can't really control such a thing.

Comment: This could be a IE specific issue. See http://kbalertz.com/196383/Windows-Opened-Script-Authentication-Session.aspx

Comment: Might be the case.. you can identify with JS the browser type and version and if old IE show some alert or message.

Comment: No, we badly need this on IE :(

Comment: So ask the users to upgrade to IE9 or at least 8 - totally legitimate, even major websites won't support ancient browsers anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason behind this behaviour is, the parent page is hosted on a IE web browser control embedded in our windows application. When it creates a new window (either using window.open or target="_blank"), the new window is owned by iexplore.exe process and doesn't inherit the session cookies from the parent IE window, which is owned by our application process. There is no generic solution to this problem. In our case, we used some kind of Single Sign On to share the session context between two window instances.

Answer (score 2):

Try this workaround, not sure it will help but worth a shot:

```
<a href="/path_to_same_page" target="mywindow" onclick="window.open('/path_to_same_page', 'mywindow', 'toolbar=0,status=0,resizable=1');">Click here...</a>
```

By having this, the window won't get opened by script initially, but rather by the `target` attribute.

Comment: No. My intention is to open the new window as a popup without address bar, toolbar stuffs..

Comment: I know, the code in the `onclick` should handle this. Did you give it a try?

Comment: Note that, the reported problem is because of onclick, because it opens the new window in a new IE process, which is not reusing the cookies from the parent window.

Answer (score 2):

You stated in your answer that

> the parent page is hosted on a IE web browser control embedded in our windows application

There actually is a solution to this problem. Your application needs to handle the `NewWindow2` event in order to maintain the session across windows.

Refer to the following MSDN resources for details on this:

- [How to use the WebBrowser control NewWindow2 event in Visual C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20150118044818/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815714)
- [How to use the WebBrowser control NewWindow2 event in Visual Basic .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20140909014521/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311282)
- [How To Use the WebBrowser Control NewWindow2 Event](https://web.archive.org/web/20140816222332/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184876) (for Visual Basic 5.0 and Visual C++ 5.0)

Comment: Fixed, I've replaced the links with the cached articles on archive.org.

Answer (score -4):

first encode that url with encodeURL(""); and then add in javascript file