# Passing data between views in Durandal

Tags: requirejs, durandal

I have a view with a grid from where I launch a different view in a new window. The parent view needs to pass data to the child view and it cannot be passed as a query string since it is pretty large. I cannot use a native modal. I am just using window.open and have not created a custom modal context.Things that I have tried

**1. Tried populating hidden field elements in the new window using something like the code below**

```
var popup = window.open('/#/viewname');
popup.onload=function(){document.findbyid('hiddenfield')= newvalue };
```

I am using a splash page to display loading in durandal , onload of the new window the router is still navigating and I get the splash page document

**2. Tried requiring the parent view in the child view and then grabbing the parent view data using something like the code below**

```
define(['viewmodels/parent'],function ('parent'){

function activate(){
localvariablevalue= parent.observable;



}

return{
activate:activate
}

});
```

I get parent.observable as undefined. More than likely it is out of context as this is a new window.

**3.Tried a singleton global.js file and requiring it in both parent and child but I think that is also losing context as I get undefined even with that approach**

Any ideas on how to achieve this.. if it can be achieved using v 1.2 ? If it can be achieved by creating a custom Modal context then can someone give some pointers on how to define the addContext function for a new window .

Comment: My stupidity knows no bounds!! As rainer pointed out in his third edit win =window.open ; win.targetwinvariable=value works just fine...No need for any complicated approaches.. 2 days down the drain!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `window.open` an independent instance of a `#/viewname` SPA gets created that has no relation to the first SPA. If you really have to open a new window than you'd need to look into other ways to exchange information between windows like e.g. [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

But you're probably better off rethinking the requirements and see if you can't achieve the goal with modals instead.

**Edit based on comment**: That has nothing to do with Durandal loosing context, it's about `window.open` not opening in the same session. see e.g. [window.open doesn't open in same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580550/window-open-doesnt-open-in-same-session/6993693#6993693)

**Edit2** As an alternative you might use the param `#/viewname` in the second windows `vm.activate` to retrieve the data either from the server directly (if applicable) or via [webstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) e.g. localstorage or sessionstorage from the first browser.

**Edit3** I did a quick test do see if that can be accomplished using `window.open` alone. Tested in Firefox/Firebug. I would still recommend to checkout the links to [webstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) to ensure that this is working cross browser.

Go to http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/, open up a console and create a global var:

```
window.myVar = {complex: true};
```

create a new window

```
var myWindow = window.open('http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/view-composition');
```

go back first console and create a property myvar on myWindow

```
myWindow.myVar = myVar;
```

change to the console of the second window and check

```
myVar // output {complex: true}
```

The alternative that I was suggesting uses the unique hash value that you pass in to the second window and then either retrieves the complex data (that can be added as query string) as part of the `activate` callback. The data could be stored on the server or via webstorage.

Comment: So what you are saying is that Durandal loses context ? Am I wrong in thinking non modal windows can be created keeping a modal context so that durandal is aware of it ?

Comment: Thanks for your response Rainer. In my case the session cannot play a role. Opening a new window and accessing javascript variable values ..no server session involved here. And  window.open doesnt change the session normally. In your example it does because they are using an embedded control instead of a browser. At this juncture the only resolution for me seems to be to emulate a new window by changing Durandal';s modal style

Comment: The data is stored in the first window in a js var I just need to pass it to the second window. So are you suggesting passing it as a query string and getting it in the activate event ? If you are that wont work for me as I mentioned in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Rainer thanks for trying to help out.  The following code will generate maximised modals. At this stage I am resigning to this solution and passing my data as activation in showModal. It is an exact copy of the default modal context with minor css variations.But posting it if it helps someone out.

**1. CSS**

```
.modalHostMax {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s linear; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s linear; 
    -o-transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}
.modalMax {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;


}
```

**2.New modal context**

```
   var addContext = function (contextName) {
            modalDialog.addContext(contextName, {
                blockoutOpacity: .2,
                removeDelay: 200,
                addHost: function (modal) {
                    var body = $('body');
                    var blockout = $('<div class="modalBlockout"></div>')
                        .css({ 'z-index': modalDialog.getNextZIndex(), 'opacity': this.blockoutOpacity })
                        .appendTo(body);

                    var host = $('<div class="modalHostMax"></div>')
                        .css({ 'z-index': modalDialog.getNextZIndex() })
                        .appendTo(body);

                    modal.host = host.get(0);
                    modal.blockout = blockout.get(0);

                    if (!modalDialog.isModalOpen()) {
                        modal.oldBodyMarginRight = $("body").css("margin-right");

                        var html = $("html");
                        var oldBodyOuterWidth = body.outerWidth(true);
                        var oldScrollTop = html.scrollTop();
                        $("html").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
                        var newBodyOuterWidth = $("body").outerWidth(true);
                        body.css("margin-right", (newBodyOuterWidth - oldBodyOuterWidth + parseInt(modal.oldBodyMarginRight)) + "px");
                        html.scrollTop(oldScrollTop); // necessary for Firefox
                        $("#simplemodal-overlay").css("width", newBodyOuterWidth + "px");


                    }


                },
                removeHost: function (modal) {
                    $(modal.host).css('opacity', 0);
                    $(modal.blockout).css('opacity', 0);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(modal.host).remove();
                        $(modal.blockout).remove();
                    }, this.removeDelay);

                    if (!modalDialog.isModalOpen()) {
                        var html = $("html");
                        var oldScrollTop = html.scrollTop(); // necessary for Firefox.
                        html.css("overflow-y", "").scrollTop(oldScrollTop);
                        $("body").css("margin-right", modal.oldBodyMarginRight);
                    }
                },
                afterCompose: function (parent, newChild, settings) {

                    var $child = $(newChild);
                    var width = $child.width();
                    var height = $child.height();



                    $child.attr('class', 'modalMax');
                    $(settings.model.modal.host).css('opacity', 1);

                    if ($(newChild).hasClass('autoclose')) {
                        $(settings.model.modal.blockout).click(function () {
                            settings.model.modal.close();
                        });
                    }

                    $('.autofocus', newChild).each(function () {
                        $(this).focus();
                    });
                }
            });
        };
```

**3. In your target view make sure that the container min-height is set to $(document).height()**

**4. To use just set custom context by calling addContext('yourcontextname').Then create your modal - app.showModal('viewname',{data},'yourcontextname')**